# Choose desktop environment programmatically

Tags: 20.04, gnome, desktop-environments, remote-desktop

I have a remote machine with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to which I have graphical access via xrdp. This  machine has 3 desktop environments installed - Gnome (i.e. standard Ubuntu desktop), KDE Plasma and Xfce. I am currently using KDE Plasma.

My question is: How do I switch to another dekstop environment (for example, Gnome), given that the machine is remote, the only access to it is SSH and RDP? I.e. now, when I connect to it via xrdp it automatically runs KDE Plasma, there's no access to normal login screen where you can choose another desktop environment session.

Comment: Do you want to install a GUI to browse everything easier on your system? It could make it easier to install a GUI graphically...

Comment: @Jeff, GUI is already installed. Moreover, I'm using KDE now. My question is about how do I switch to another desktop environment so that it will appear, when I connect to machine via RDP.

Comment: Try installing `gnome-remote-desktop`. It is a remote graphical environment and should allow you to view the desktop graphically via RDP. Sorry about the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal login splash screen is presented to you by a Display Manager. xrdp does not do that since it's connecting you directly to the desktop, in your case KDE Plasma.

You can set another desktop environment by creating the configuration file
~/.Xclients, like so:

```
echo "gnome-session" > ~/.Xclients
chmod +x ~/.Xclients
sudo systemctl restart xrdp.service
```

Another way would be using a product which let's you choose a desktop environment upon login, like it would normally do if you were sitting locally infront of your server. ThinLinc for example would let you do this. There are thinlinc clients for every major platform, and the server installer is easy enough for anyone with a bit of experience to manage to install it.

/Martin

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: @ivan.ukr - I believe the answer below is what you're looking for. Let me know if it works out by accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default desktop for all remote xrdp connections in Ubuntu 20 (in my case, I wanted to change to cinnamon desktop) I found I could edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh and replaced this:

```
test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

with this:

```
# test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /usr/bin/cinnamon-session-cinnamon
```

And it made it so all of my client rdp sessions, when connected, would start cinnamon. Each user id will have it's own cinnamon session when logged in via xrdp. Note xrdp default is to limit xrdp to 50 concurrent users. Just pointing out there may be other limitations unrelated to which desktop you launch.